# Qt: Qml: Focus on text field when a dialog is created

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qqmlcomponent

I have a simple dialog that has two text fields. **I would like to have the text field `labelField` focused when `AddPasswordDialog` dialog shows up.** How can I achieve that?

I asked this question and I was asked to provide a MCVE, and here I provide it. Please ask for more info if you need it.

`main.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Stack")

    header: ToolBar {
        contentHeight: toolButton.implicitHeight

        ToolButton {
            id: toolButton
            text: stackView.depth > 1 ? "\u25C0" : "\u2630"
            onClicked: {
                if (stackView.depth > 1) {
                    stackView.pop()
                } else {
                    drawer.open()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    StackView {
        id: stackView
        initialItem: "app/qml/HomeForm.qml"
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

`HomeForm.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2


Page {
    id: mainPage

    title: qsTr("Home")

    GridLayout {
        id: homeGrid
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 10
        rows: 2
        columns: 2

        Button {
            id: addButton
            text: "Add"
            Layout.row: 0
            Layout.column: 0
            anchors.right: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.topMargin: 5
            onClicked: {
                var component = Qt.createComponent("AddPasswordDialog.qml")
                var loadAddPwDialog = component.createObject(mainPage)
//                loadAddPwDialog.labelField.forceActiveFocus()
                loadAddPwDialog.open()
                if (component.status === Component.Error) {
                    console.log("Error")
                }
            }
        }

        Button {
            id: removeButton
            text: "Remove"
            Layout.row: 0
            Layout.column: 1
            anchors.left: addButton.right
            anchors.topMargin: 5
            anchors.leftMargin: 5
        }
    }
}
```

`AddPasswordDialog.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Dialog {
    id: addPwDialog
    modality: Qt.WindowModal
    title: "Add a new password"
    standardButtons: StandardButton.Save | StandardButton.Cancel
    onAccepted: {
        console.log("Accepted")
//        pwDataModel.addPassword(labelField.text, pwField.text)
    }

    GridLayout {

        TextField {
            id: labelField
            placeholderText: "Label"
            focus: true
            Layout.row: 0
            Layout.column: 0
        }

        TextField {
            id: pwField
            placeholderText: "Password"
            Layout.row: 1
            Layout.column: 0
        }
    }
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QQmlComponent>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("app/qml/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must activate the focus of `labelField` when the Dialog is visible.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Dialog {
    id: addPwDialog
    modality: Qt.WindowModal
    title: "Add a new password"
    standardButtons: StandardButton.Save | StandardButton.Cancel
    onAccepted: {
        console.log("Accepted")
        //pwDataModel.addPassword(labelField.text, pwField.text)
    }
    onVisibleChanged: if(visible) labelField.focus = true

    GridLayout {

        TextField {
            id: labelField
            placeholderText: "Label"
            Layout.row: 0
            Layout.column: 0
        }

        TextField {
            id: pwField
            placeholderText: "Password"
            Layout.row: 1
            Layout.column: 0
        }
    }
}
```